# Can you assign properties to an object and its prototype in the same block?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a constructor and assign both it and its prototype some properties. To condense the code and group similar ideas, I want to find a way to do this within the same block.

For example:

```
const Collection = {

    FirstClass: function() {

        this.propertyTheSecond = 'i am not a default';

    }

    // insert a buuunch of code here

};

Collection.FirstClass.staticProperty = 42;

Collection.FirstClass.prototype.propertyTheFirst = 'hello i am a default';
```

I want to condense this into a single block so that the three "types" of blocks won't be separated from each other.

I can do this with `staticProperty`, but I am unsure of how to do this with `propertyTheFirst`.

```
const Collection = {

    FirstClass: Object.assign( function() {

        this.propertyTheSecond = 'i am not a default';

    }, {

        staticProperty: 42

    } )

    // insert a buuunch of code here

};

Collection.FirstClass.prototype.propertyTheFirst = 'hello i am a default';
```

I was hoping for something like this:

```
const Collection = {

    FirstClass: Object.assign( Object.assign( function() {

        this.propertyTheSecond = 'i am not a default';

    }, {

        staticProperty: 42

    } ).prototype, {

        propertyTheFirst: 'hello i am a default'

    } )

    // insert a buuunch of code here

};
```

However, this doesn't work, because the ultimate return value is the prototype, not the constructor.

Is there a fairly straightforward way to do this that I am missing?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a fairly straightforward way to do this that I am missing?

If your objective is to logically group related code, the most straightforward and modern approach would be to use something similar to your first example, but to isolate it *in its own module* and export the `Collection`, without messing with confusing chained `Object.assign`s. If the `Collection` and properties assigned to it is the only code in the module, it's quite easy to understand.

Another way is to use an IIFE:

```
const Collection = (() => {
    const Collection = {

        FirstClass: function() {

            this.propertyTheSecond = 'i am not a default';

        }

        // insert a buuunch of code here

    };

    Collection.FirstClass.staticProperty = 42;

    Collection.FirstClass.prototype.propertyTheFirst = 'hello i am a default';
    return Collection;
})();
```

It's technically possible to do this with `Object.assign`s, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
const Collection = {
    FirstClass: Object.assign(
        function () { this.propertyTheSecond = 'i am not a default'; },
        {
            staticProperty: 42,
            prototype: {
                propertyTheFirst: 'hello i am a default'
            }
        }
    )
};
```

Comment: I should have checked.. but I didn't even attempt this because I thought this would overwrite the prototype, rather than recursively assign. But your input was valuable! Perhaps I should make it more modular